# Tcolorbox counters with TeX4ht

Tags: tcolorbox, tex4ht

Only the first numbered environment created with `tcolorbox` gets an `<a>` tag destination in the HTML when converted with `htlatex`. Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\newtcbtheorem{theorem}{}{}{th}
\crefname{tcb@cnt@theorem}{theorem}{theorems}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}{}{1}
    Text
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}{}{2}
    Text
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

This results in the following HTML:

```
<div class="tcolorbox theorem" id="tcolobox-1">
  <a id="x1-1doc"></a> 
  <div class="tcolorbox-title">...</div>
  <div class="tcolorbox-content">...</div>
</div>
<div class="tcolorbox theorem" id="tcolobox-2">
  <div class="tcolorbox-title">...</div>
  <div class="tcolorbox-content">...</div> 
</div>
```

Here, only the first theorem got the `<a id="x1-1doc"></a>` tag. Cross references to the theorems, `\cref{th:1}` and `\cref{th:2}`, yield "theorem 1" and "theorem 2", but both link to the first one: `<a href="#x1-1doc">`. Moreover, a plain `\ref{th:1}` does not produce any output.

Is there a way to give every instance of `theorem` a unique `<a>` tag destination? Moreover, this should also work for other environments defined via `tcolorbox`. Lastly, is there a way to get `\ref` to work for these environments?

**UPDATE**

michal.h21 posted a [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/623697/44413) that ensures that every environment has a unique link destination. This works fine if the document only uses one type of environment defined via `tcolorbox`. However, consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\newtcbtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}{}{th}
\newtcbtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}{}{lem}
\crefname{tcb@cnt@theorem}{theorem}{theorems}
\crefname{tcb@cnt@lemma}{lemma}{lemmas}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}{}{1}
    Text
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}{}{2}
    Text
\end{theorem}

\begin{lemma}{}{}
    Text
\end{lemma}

See \cref{th:1} and \cref{th:2}.

\end{document}
```

This renders as
[image]
Here the last reference is incorrectly printed as "lemma 1" instead of "theorem 2". How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TeX4ht needs special treatment for labels. It works out of the box for commands and environments that update their counters using `\refstepcounter`, but it seems that `tcolorbox` uses it's own mechanism for label handling. In this case, we need to insert destination link for the current label using `\AnchorLabel` command. This is the updated version of `tcolorbox.4ht` that uses it:

```
% tcolorbox.4ht (2020-12-03-13:56), generated from tex4ht-4ht.tex
% Copyright 2020 TeX Users Group
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either
% version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any
% later version. The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions
% of LaTeX version 2005/12/01 or later.
%
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained".
%
% The Current Maintainer of this work
% is the TeX4ht Project <http://tug.org/tex4ht>.
%
% If you modify this program, changing the
% version identification would be appreciated.
\immediate\write-1{version 2020-12-03-13:56}


% use custom counter that increments for every \tcolorbox
\newcounter{:tcbcolcount}

\def\tcb@drawcolorbox{%
  % save text and background colors for use in CSS
  \stepcounter{:tcbcolcount}%
  \get:xcolorcss{tcbcolbacktitle}\:tcbcolbacktitle%
  \get:xcolorcss{tcbcoltitle}\:tcbcoltitle%
  \get:xcolorcss{tcbcolback}\:tcbcolback%
  \get:xcolorcss{tcbcolframe}\:tcbcolframe%
  \get:xcolorcss{tcbcolupper}\:tcbcolupper%
  % make unique ID for this box
  \def\:tcbcolid{tcolobox-\arabic{:tcbcolcount}}
  % Open box
  \a:tcolorbox%
  % save label, if it is set
  \ifdefined\tcolorbox:label:key%
    \AnchorLabel%
    \label{\tcolorbox:label:key}%
    \global\let\tcolorbox:label:key\undefined
  \fi%
  % open title
  \b:tcolorbox%
  \kvtcb@before@title\kvtcb@title\kvtcb@after@title%
  % close title and open main box
  \c:tcolorbox%
  \box\tcb@upperbox%
  % deal with lower box, if it is set
  \iftcb@hasLower%
    \a:tcolorlowerbox%
    \box\tcb@lowerbox%
    \b:tcolorlowerbox%
  \fi%
  % close box
  \d:tcolorbox%
}

% overwrite other versions of box drawing macros
\let\tcb@drawcolorbox@standalone\tcb@drawcolorbox

\NewConfigure{tcolorbox}{4}
\NewConfigure{tcolorlowerbox}{2}

% we need to save label for a later use
\def\:tempa#1{%
  \xdef\tcolorbox:label:key{#1}%
  \o:tcb@set@label:{#1}%
}
\HLet\tcb@set@label\:tempa


% this is a trick to fix issues with paragraphs
% spurious end </p> tags were inserted
\def\tcb@minipage#1{\SaveEndP\vbox\bgroup\par}
\def\endtcb@savebox{\EndP\egroup\RecallEndP}

\Hinput{tcolorbox}
\endinput
```

The changed code is this:

```
  \ifdefined\tcolorbox:label:key%
    \AnchorLabel%
    \label{\tcolorbox:label:key}%
    \global\let\tcolorbox:label:key\undefined
  \fi%
```

It inserts the link destination just before `\label`.

This is the resulting HTML code:

```html
 <div class='tcolorbox theorem' id='tcolobox-1'>   <a id='x1-3x'></a><a id='x1-3xdoc'></a> 
<div class='tcolorbox-title'>
<!-- l. 12 --><p class='indent'>    1</p></div> 
<div class='tcolorbox-content'><!-- l. 11 --><p class='noindent'>Text</p>                                                                                                  
</div> 
</div>
   <div class='tcolorbox theorem' id='tcolobox-2'>   <a id='x1-5x'></a><a id='x1-5xdoc'></a> 
<div class='tcolorbox-title'>
<!-- l. 16 --><p class='indent'>    2</p></div> 
<div class='tcolorbox-content'><!-- l. 15 --><p class='noindent'>Text</p>                                                                                                  
</div> 
</div>
<!-- l. 18 --><p class='noindent'>See <a href='#x1-3xdoc'>theorem 1</a> and <a href='#x1-5xdoc'>theorem 2</a>
</p>
```

And rendered HTML:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Now every environment has a unique link destination. However, there is still an issue with multiple environments defined by `tcolorbox`. I'll update the question to make it clearer.

Comment: @user44413 ah, you are right. I forgot to erase the label after use.